# Spring REST service doesn't fired with certain symbols in URL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I work on rest service on java. This service include Spring mvc model. And it works ok, but when i use Russian char **х** in url, i have 404 and spring method in controller doesn't run. I transfer this data with url encode.

> localhost:8080/x/test

Service code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getListOfResources(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {

           System.out.println(test);

    }
```

Comment: The Russian char is probably not valid for URL. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#List_of_allowed_URL_characters) for valid characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in file server.xml in tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to look at the configuration in your server.xml (if using Tomcat) and check URIEncoding.
Jetty defaults to UTF-8, more information: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/International_Characters

You have to define UTF-8 also in the web.xml, a filter like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me.